# Extra 0's after rounding

Tags: python

In a project i am doing for AP CSP, I am attempting to make a calculator that can do sig figs, and there is always a ton of extra 0's after i round the number as seen in the picture i attached
[image]

the code if anybody needs it is

````
import math
def find_op():
    print("Sig Fig Calculator")
    print("Choose an operation")
    operation = str(input("What operation do you want to do?"))
    operation = operation.lower()
    return operation

def find_sigfig(number_str):
    snum = number_str.lstrip('0')
    msnum = snum if "." in str(snum) else snum.rstrip("0")
    sigfig = len(msnum)
    return sigfig

def round_to_sigfig(number, k):
    has_decimal = '.' in str(number)
    if has_decimal:
        factor = 10**(-k + len(str(number).split('.')[1]))
    else:
        factor = 10**(k - len(str(number).rstrip('0')))
    rounded_number = round(number / factor) * factor
    rounded_number = float(rounded_number) if has_decimal else int(rounded_number)
    rounded_number = float(str(rounded_number))
    return rounded_number

oper = find_op()
if oper == "add" or oper == "addition":
    anum = int(input("how many numbers do you want to add?"))
    tsum = 0
    lowestsigfig = 100
    for _i in range(anum):
        num = float(input("what number is it:"))
        sigfig = find_sigfig(str(num))
        if sigfig < lowestsigfig:
            lowestsigfig = sigfig
        tsum += num

    rounded_num = round_to_sigfig(tsum, lowestsigfig)
    print(rounded_num)
```
````

Comment: Are you asking us to remove the extra zeros?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this:

```
def round_to_sigfig(number, k):
    has_decimal = '.' in str(number)
    if has_decimal:
        factor = 10**(-k + len(str(number).split('.')[1]))  # -2 + 1, given (443.7, 2)
    else:
        ...
    rounded_number = round(number / factor) * factor
    ...
    return rounded_number
```

Here is your summary complaint:

```
>>> n = 0 + 142.5 + 301.2
>>> factor = .1
>>> 
>>> round(n / factor) * factor
443.70000000000005
>>>
>>> 4437 * .1
443.70000000000005
>>> 
>>> round(n / factor) * factor - 443.7
5.684341886080802e-14
```

Either you're saying you're unhappy that one of the constituents
of base ten (2 × 5) is odd (that would be the five),
or you're shaking the five fingers of your fist at William Kahan. Rail all you like,
but that won't change the nature of arithmetic, and it won't change the
[IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) spec.

You seem to have beliefs about the `round(number / factor) * factor`
expression, which simply aren't true.
When a mathematician writes things down,
there are lots of cool properties like associativity
and commutativity that hold *all the time*.
When a computer scientist writes down the
same things, for evaluation by a 64-bit FPU,
there's a different set of rules in play.
Sometimes multiplying `(1/x) * x` gives
the multiplicative identity.
But not always.
It's [complicated](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

You will want to rethink your approach to this problem.

Consider using the scaled integer
[Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) class.
Or you might even focus on the `str()` representation of floats.